Dynamic layouts in UICollectionViewCell
I am developing a data dashboard of sorts and am trying to use UIViewCollection, one cell per indicator. On displays that are sufficiently wide, I want to implement a standard cell size like this:

But on smaller or narrower displays, I want to use a one-column display like this:

To change cell dimensions (in Swift) I am subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout like this:
class SBCollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {    
    override func prepare() {
    
        if let view = collectionView {
            let width = view.frame.width
            if width < 375 {
                self.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 50)
            }
            else {
                self.itemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 110)
            }
        }
    }
}

So that handles the cell resizing well enough, but I'm a bit stumped on how to dynamically adjust the layout of objects within the cell according to the size of the cell. For instance, I'd like to adjust the font size in the labels and align them vertically instead of on top of each other.
In analogous situations I've written two sets of programmatic constraints on the child views (text labels in this case) and enabled one set or the other with addConstraints/removeConstraints. Is that the way to go in this case, and if so, where would I add code to adjust the constraints?
The other approach I can think of is to replace one UICollectionViewCell subclass with another and trigger the replacement by calling UICollectionView.reloadData, but that seems really inelegant.
Or is there another approach?

addConstraints/removeConstraints.  should be good way, func collectionView(UICollectionView, willDisplay: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt: IndexPath) you may check ?

Thank you @shivbabas-son that was the missing puzzle piece I needed. So I added code in my UICollectionViewDelegate to the effect:
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    if let c = cell as? SBCollectionViewCell1 {
        let constraints:NSLayoutConstraint = [...]
        if cell.frame.width < 375 {
            cell.contentView.addConstraints(constraints)
        }
        else {
         
   cell.contentView.removeConstraints(constraints)
        }
    }
}

Tada!
UPDATE
After a bit more experimentation, I found that collectionView(collectionView:willDisplay:forItemAt) isn't quite sufficient, as it doesn't get called (or recalled) for all cells after a window size change. So I also had to add the following to my UIViewController:
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: any UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        if self.display != nil {
            self.display.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

